# Android: сделать из статической переменной динамическую

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Есть следующая статическая переменная в android:

> `static java.lang.Integer var = 1;`

Существует ли функция Java, которая может сделать эту переменную динамической?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Статическая переменная существует в классе в единственном экземпляре, вне зависимости от объекта класса. Вы можете создать динамическую переменную и присвоить ей значение статической

Comment: То есть всё-таки переделать статическую переменную невозможно?

Comment: Можете, в коде:) ключевое слово static для того и существует, чтобы обращаться к полям или методам даже без создания объекта класса. Если сделаете класс MyClass, со статической переменой static int i = 3, то даже если создадите и объявите объект MyClass object = null, то вызов метода System.out.println(object.i) выведет Вам 3. А динамическая переменная не существует без объекта класса, поэтому нет, невозможно.